# PHP: Determine if file is on removable media

Tags: php, removable-storage

My current project, written in PHP, requires that certain extraneous file be removed from a volume, if that volume is removable.

The project scans for JPEG and MPEG files, and moves them from the specified source to the specified target (with renames according to metadata and time).

An example might be:

```
/Volumes/volume/DCIM/100MEDIA/IMG00005.JPG -> /Target/Dir/Boston-230403-0005.jpg
```

Once the task is done, the DCIM/100MEDIA folder (in this case) is removed if empty.  The new project requirement is that, if (e.g.) /Volumes/volume is removable media, then also remove the following folders and their content if they exist:

```
(root)/.Trashes
(root)/.Spotlight-V100
(root)/.fseventsd
```

In general, the application is used to move files from removable media to fixed (a smart SD card unloader), but it does not always have to be used that way.  However, the new requirement dictates that the removal of those folders (.Trashes, .fseventsd, .Spotlight-V100) must be done only against removable media.

Hence the question: Is there a reasonable and reliable method available to determine if a named file represents removable media?  fstat() will reveal the device number (['dev'] element), and that is probably the needed hook... but from that, can we get to the type of device?  And will such device type tell us what we need to know?

A klunky alternative is, rather than looking at device type, to look for '/DCIM/' in the pathname, and to remove those folders from that same point in the path, a la:

```
/Volumes/media/DCIM/Camera_01
/Volumes/media/.Trashes
/Volumes/media/.fseventsd
/Volumes/media/.Spotlight-V100
```

It just feels like things may go wrong with that approach...

NOTE: Mac users may recognize those names, and [correctly] assume this is being done on a Mac.  While a portable solution is desired, a Mac-specific solution may be necessary.  That's OK in this instance.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the problem. To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and its linked resources.

Comment: Not sure how I gave the impression that something's broken; there is no problem to demonstrate/reproduce, and I thought the question was clear about that.  This is a quest for what _can_ by tried.  On the research side, I have pored through PHP documentation regarding filesystems and the like, I've tried to find what clue fstat($file)['dev'] can give me, tried (unsuccessfully) to discover what tells "finder" which drives may be "ejected" and which may not, et cetera.  I thought the question was very clear; the purpose clearly stated.

Comment: I don't recall having seen such PHP function. But you can invoke external commands, so you can implement a solution for each operating system you want to support. It doesn't look trivial, though: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/613804/determine-if-a-given-path-is-on-a-removable-device-even-if-encrypted-via-bash